# How can I delete all user data when deleting profile on Django using signals.py

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-signals

how can I delete all user data when deleting a user profile on Django using signals.py? I am trying to delete a custom user model using Django and when the profile is deleted I want to delete all data of that user using signals.py how can I create it?

```
@receiver(post_delete, sender=models.Profile_user)
def delete_auth_user_model_handler(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    user_instance = instance.user
    user_instance.delete()
```

I want to delete blogs of the user-written when the profile is deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just declare your `models` as `ForeignKeys` to your `user`. This way when you delete the `user` , everything associated with it will be deleted:

```
class Blogs(models.Model):
author= models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
```